# Why do I get duplicate reports reading from a usb device on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, linux-kernel, usb, hid

I want to read data from a custom USB HID device on a Raspberry Pi running the current Raspberry Pi OS with a 5.15.32 Kernel. The device has 2 operating modes

1. standard hid mode: sending standard hid reports, and
2. custom mode: sending custom ~1kb reports, enabled by sending a specific feature report.

On Windows, I'm using python hidapi (https://pypi.org/project/hidapi/) to send the feature report to enable the custom mode. Then I can read all the custom reports at full speed (~4250 reports/sec) using a [hid.device.read()](https://trezor.github.io/cython-hidapi/api.html#hid.device.read) as in the [example](https://trezor.github.io/cython-hidapi/examples.html#connecting-reading-and-writing). The custom reports have a `report_number`, that guarantees, that I am not missing any reports.

On my Raspberry Pi, I am using the same python code (using the python hidapi package with the libusb backend, the hidraw backend is too slow), but run into the following problem:

At the beginning I get all the reports in the correct order - missing some at startup, but this is ok. After some seconds, I start getting duplicate reports. These duplicate reports arrive in blocks of consecutive reports. In terms of the `report_number` it looks something like this

```
1,2,...,578,  238,239,...,816,  476,477,...,1054, and so on
```

So in this example, I always get approx. 578 consecutive reports, and then again approx. 578 consecutive reports, but starting in the *past*. In this example I am getting a report that is 340 reports in the *past*, which I have already received previously.

I have tried with the [libusb](https://pypi.org/project/libusb1/) python binding or the C [hidapi](https://github.com/libusb/hidapi) library, but this reproduces the same patterns in the `report_number`s.

To get a better understanding I used wireshark/tshark or plain usbmon to snoop at the usb communication and did the following:

1. Open the device and send the feature report to enable custom mode
2. Record the usb communication

After opening the device with cython-hidapi, the driver of the device changes from `usbhid` to `usbfs`. The recorded reports show the same pattern. I do **not** need to read anything from the device explicitly. I tried debugging further with usbmon, but logging debug messages slowed things down and lead to missed reports, but did not show the "jumps" into the past anymore.

I'm suspecting that the cause of the duplicate reports might lie in the device drivers and the pattern reminds me of a "race" on a ring buffer between en- and dequeue pointers. If I understand correctly the device drivers used are `usbfs` (`usbhid`) and `xhci_hcd`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lspci -k
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM2711 PCIe Bridge (rev 20)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
01:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

I have tried the setup on a custom linux with a 5.15.61 kernel on Raspberry Pi and an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop with similar results.

I would greatly appreciate any advice, pointers to further debugging possibilities or similar issues.

Comment: So you're saying that the custom HID device is *actually* sending duplicate and out-of-order reports?  Then if we're going to debug it we need to know all about that HID device and see its code, because that is the device that is misbehaving.  The details of what drivers are used in the Linux kernel on your Raspberry Pi (which is acting as the USB host) do not matter at all.

Comment: Thank you for asking. I'm afraid the USB device does not know anything about the past, so it cannot re-send the old reports and it is sending the reports in the correct order on windows, which I thought indicates that the device is correctly providing the reports. I was also not expecting that the linux device drivers to be the cause of this phenomenon, since they are working perfectly with so many devices. Could it be due to multiple transfers being submitted? I think this is what is done in the libusb backend.

Comment: You said "The recorded reports show the same pattern." which to me means that your custom HID device is actually sending old and out of order reports.  This contradicts your statement "it cannot send the old reports".  You need to first figure out if the USB HID device is malfunctioning or your USB host is malfunctioning, then debug the device that is malfunctioning, but your descriptions are confusing and contradictory.  (P.S. Your HID device knows nothing about how many transfers are queued by libusb on the host side.)

Comment: Also, just because it works well with Windows doesn't tell you which device is malfunctioning when it's talking to a Linux machine.  The Linux USB host might be setting up your device in a slightly different way which triggers bugs in the device's firmware.  I recommend looking carefully at the actual USB packets on the wire when your system is experiencing the problem.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thanks for your comments. I'm trying to understand the problem from both sides - the host and the device. Do you have any advice or tools that I can use to verify that the host is working as expected? Is there a way to "mock" the device?

Comment: Designing and coding a mock device is going to be a lot of trouble.  Since you don't trust your USB host, I would get a hardware USB protocol analyzer like the Total Phase Beagle 12 and control it from a separate computer running an OS that you trust, so you can see the actual packets.  (By the way, I trust the well-tested Linux Kernel and the Raspberry Pi way more than a mysterious custom HID device.)